# Why would custom module code fail when called from drush but work fine when invoked from cron button in admin/config/system/cron?

Tags: 7, drush

Background: I have developed a custom module to process a CSV file of user data imported from an external system. The module updates the standard Drupal user fields and also their Profile 2 fields. I have tested this via pressing the cron button on admin/config/system/cron and it works fine. However, ultimately I don't want to run this with cron but instead at a single specific time regular time. I want to invoke it via Jenkins issuing a drush command. So I implemented a drush command and issued this and got the following (names have been changed in case of an issues making public). Here's what I see when I issued the drush command (my development environment details follow the output):

```
$ drush mysync
WD user: PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'name' at row 1: INSERT INTO {users} (uid, name, pass, mail, created, status,  [error]
init, data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
:db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 17328
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => RequestTimeTooSmywebsiteedThe difference between the request time and the current time is too
large.20151222T173152Z2015-12-22T17:50:06Z9000007C6B68377122D467B3WpFicMSuociMXhAz4zJ4aydh6THmo7Q5gcBRkVdY86d962a3J+F+wx93sgHOdFQIUZYpg4pLE=
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => $S$D9dNnB8ROhS9.EZudAfxp/dvkbD1f4HswTAzRJ1q4KbaldtmzwzR
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1450805510
    [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1
    [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => a:2:{s:7:"contact";i:1;s:17:"mimemail_textonly";i:0;}
)
 in drupal_write_record() (line 7316 of /var/www/mywebsite.dev/includes/common.inc).
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'name' at row 1' in                                            [error]
/var/www/mywebsite.dev/includes/database/database.inc:2171
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/includes/database/database.inc(2171): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/includes/database/database.inc(683): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/includes/database/mysql/query.inc(36): DatabaseConnection->query('INSERT INTO {us...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/includes/common.inc(7316): InsertQuery_mysql->execute()
#4 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/modules/user/user.module(582): drupal_write_record('users', Object(stdClass))
#5 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/sites/all/modules/custom/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.module(564): user_save('', Array)
#6 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/sites/all/modules/custom/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.module(239): _mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_create_new_user(Array)
#7 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/sites/all/modules/custom/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.module(26): _mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_update_and_create_user_records(Array)
#8 /var/www/mywebsite.dev/sites/all/modules/custom/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration/mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.drush.inc(17): _mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_sync()
#9 [internal function]: drush_mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_externalsystem_sync_command()
#10 /usr/share/drush/includes/command.inc(359): call_user_func_array('drush_mywebsite_ag...', Array)
#11 /usr/share/drush/includes/command.inc(210): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#12 [internal function]: drush_command()
#13 /usr/share/drush/includes/command.inc(178): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#14 /usr/share/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(62): drush_dispatch(Array)
#15 /usr/share/drush/drush.php(70): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#16 /usr/share/drush/drush.php(11): drush_main()
#17 {main}
```

My environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04 Linux VM provisioned via puphpet.com manifest using Vagrant running on Mac OS X El Capitan
- PHP version: PHP 5.6.16-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
- I have compared the php.ini files for Apache (Web) and for CLI (that drush uses) - see screenshot (the file names have been renamed and moved to a position where my host comparison tool, Beyond Compare can compare them in the shared file system of the VM):

[image: php.ini comparison between apache (web) and CLI (drush)]

- I did some research and a plausible reason for the error is that the UTF character set is different, e.g. it was UTF-8 on apache (where it worked and perhaps UTF-16 on drush cli where it fails with the truncation - because twice the width, however, they are both the same:

[image: utf-8 is the same]

I just don't understand why this code would work when run within Drupal via the web, but not in drush. The database attempted to be written to is the same, the data I'm attempting to write is the same, it must be some kind of environmental difference, but apart from php.ini I don't know what it could be. Please advise.

Comment: Does your web server perhaps set up some LOCALE environment variables that are not set for Drush?  Check `printenv` in the shell against the list of environment variables in `phpinfo()` from the web server.

Comment: +1 I agree thanks I think that is worth me exploring further. (ust following up on this after the holidays, sorry for lack of further feedback since last time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're having MySQL error, you should rather check `my.cnf`, not `php.ini`, unless PHP CLI and Apache are using different instances of MySQL (via `mysql.sock`).

However your problem is something else.

You you look closely into the error:

> Data too long for column 'name' at row 1

it complains that your `name` column is too long.

Now check your db placeholders:

`uid`:

```
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 17328
```

`name`:

```
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] => RequestTimeTooSmywebsiteedThe difference between the request time and the current time is too
```

that means you've problem with the username, as above value is not valid username, secondly it's too long.

So you've to double check the code in:

```
mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.module:564: user_save('', Array)
```

and its `Array` (especially value of `name`).

The way how you call it:

```
#5 mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.module(564): user_save('', Array)
#6 mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.module(239): _mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_create_new_user(Array)
#7 mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.module(26): _mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_update_and_create_user_records(Array)
#8 mywebsite_externalsystem_integration.drush.inc(17): _mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_sync()
```

doesn't seems you're running cron task from your code (but executing custom `drush` command), so nothing to do with it, that's why it's not happening during your `cron.php`.

So to summarize it, this is a bug of your custom code which you need to find and fix it.

---

Check: [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) API for the valid syntax, where:

> `$edit`: An array of fields and values to save. For example array('name' => 'My name').

---

Going more deeply, the following error (changed based on my assumption):

> RequestTimeTooSkewed: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.

sounds like the error of Amazon S3 service (possibly you're using [Storage API](https://www.drupal.org/project/storage_api) module). So I assuming your code doesn't have failing scenario and populating the error message, instead of the username (connecting issues?).

So the only difference between Web and drush is how the code implements the user import. If you're using some specific credentials or performing HTTP requests, make sure you're loading the right variables, site profile, using the right host, proxy settings, etc. Plus print some debugs (`-v`/`-d`). For example:

```
drush -vd -l http://mywebsite.dev mysync
```

and check your watchdog messages (`drush ws --tail`).

Some people [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4770635/55075) that your local box is out of sync with the current time, so try to correct it.

So please double check that you followed installation instruction of the module correctly, as below:

> This service requires an account with the external service provider.
>   Please refer to the online documentation for additional help:
>   https://www.drupal.org/node/656716

See: [Amazon S3](https://www.drupal.org/node/656716) at Drupal.org

So [possible solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/2002236) is to run as root the following commands:

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
echo "ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/cron.daily/ntpdate && chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/ntpdate
```

depending on your Linux distribution.

Comment: "doesn't seems you're running cron task from your code (but executing custom drush command), so nothing to do with it, that's why it's not happening during your cron.php." Yes correct as I had said in the question: I am now running my code from a custom drush command (where I am now seeing these errors) but *was* running the same code from cron (where I did not see these errors)

Comment: @therobyouknow During cron probably the same functions weren't executed the same way as you do now, as it seems you're passing the wrong parameters when invoking via `drush`. If you can provide further info, such as content of `_mywebsite_externalsystem_integration_create_new_user()` function, it'll be easier to know what's going on. Especially the part how `$edit` array is generated for `user_save()`. In my opinion it's definitely human error in the code, not PHP or MySQL configuration. So check how do you implement your code.

Comment: @therobyouknow If you're using Amazon S3 services and your import has anything to do with it, check my updated answer.

Comment: +1 upvote on answer and +1 on your comments. Just following up on this after the holidays, sorry for lack of further feedback since last time. I'm re-reading the answer - this is a really good response kenorb - there are some good leads for me to follow. Good point about storing the error message in the username issue - I think that is definitely something I should correct in my code, also the environmental differences thoughts (also from greg_1_anderson).

Comment: Accepted answer. The root cause I think is that the clock on my VM compared to that on S3 is too different so S3 raises an error but the error is reported in the contents of the file that I'm supposed to be reading from S3 which explains why the value being written was flagged up as being too large. So kenorb was right about my code being incorrect - I have adjusted it to handle this scenario by checking the number of columns - which would be 1 if this were the case in this error, rather than the 19 I'm expecting for my case.

Comment: I could try to look at implementing further checks but I think I'd be adjusting the way the libraries I'm using work themselves and I don't think this is necessary at the moment. I'm using the S3fsStreamWrapper class provided in Drupal Contrib module [s3fs](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) and the setup steps I did are [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2596683#comment-10467823)